# Android: fragments overlapping

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

The fragment is overlapping on another fragment during the transition. How can I fix it?

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    initAdapter()
    newsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {
        val bundle = bundleOf("article" to it)
        view.findNavController().navigate(
            R.id.action_mainFragment_to_detailsFragment,
            bundle
        )
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "during" transition? Do you want just blink it or what?

Comment: As I move from one fragment to another, they merge. is it understandble? (sry for my bad eng)

Comment: https://imgur.com/vJQcvCD

Comment: Oh, your second fragment doesn't have a background.

Comment: Yeah, give the fragment's main layout a `background` value - if you don't, they're basically like a transparent sheet (which isn't usually a problem!). You might want `?android:attr/background`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rzIQ80k 

this helped me. change here animation

Answer (score 1):

This helped me, try to change the animation in navGraph:

```
<action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_detailsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/detailsFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
```